# Why does Aquafina explode when frozen?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, low-temperature-physics

I put two Aquafinas in the freezer this morning "for a few minutes" but then forgot to take them out.

Tonight, I opened the freezer. Both cans had exploded; on one, the top was blown off; on the other, it was more a belly rupture.

This is how they look:

[image]

Why would this happen? Other soft drinks don't do this, I don't think (maybe I'm wrong). What ingredient cannot endure being frozen without expanding?

Comment: Water. It expands about 10 % when it freezes. It is why ice floats.

Comment: This is nice ice foam that you have there ... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Water cannot "endure being frozen without expanding".

I do not know what Aquafina is, but I assume it is a soft drink, i.e. it is mostly water, plus sugar and flavourings.

Water expands when it freezes. This is unlike most other materials (including aluminium cans) which shrink when freezing.

In your case, the expanding water required more volume than was available in the can. If the can cannot expand sufficiently (e.g. by pushing out the bottom) to hold the expanded water something has to give. It may be that the can's pull-tab pops off and the water can push its way out. If that doesn't happen, the can may burst, as in your case. Which will happen depends on many factors, including the thickness of he aluminium, and the design of the can's top and bottom.